# Сравнение значений в двух списках Python

Tags: python, списки

Есть список

```
number1=[1,2,3]
number2=[1,2,3]
power1=[50,100,150]
power2=[25,150,300]

x1=zip(number1,power1)
x2=zip(number2,power2)
```

Как мне выполнить сравнение двух списков (50>25, 100>150 и тд), при условии, что i в number1 == i в number2.
В итоге должен быть список состоящий из двух список: number1, результат (true/false)

Comment: Текущая постановка задачи непонятна. Зачем делается zip списков numberX и powerX? Судя по примеру в скобках, сравнивать надо числа из списков power, но пишите вы почему-то про списки number. Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: `items = [a > b for a, b in zip(power1, power2)]` `print(items)  # [True, False, False]` ?

Comment: `list(map(lambda x, y: x > y, power1, power2))`

Comment: @slippyk, `lambda x, y: x > y` -> `operator.gt`

Comment: @mkkik, вот вы сразу поймете что `gt` это `>`? :) Я вот нет. Да и импортировать что-то только ради одной функции, если она спокойно заменяется лямбдой, думаю не нужно

Comment: @gil9red, дело вкуса. Мне кажется, что читаемость наоборот повышается.

Answer (score 1):

```
power1=[50,100,150]
power2=[25,150,300]

result = []
for i in range(len(power1)):
    result.append(power1[i] > power2[i])

# список списков с индексом
#   result.append([i+1, power1[i] > power2[i]])
# чтобы получить [[1, True], [2, False], [3, False]]

print result
# [True, False, False]
```

или

```
print [q > w for q,w in zip(power1, power2)]
# [True, False, False]
```

Comment: цикл в одну строку: `result = [power1[i] > power2[i] for i in range(len(power1))]`

Comment: а как же простые примеры без сахара?

Comment: Они тоже нужны, в принципе, вы можете оба вариант указывать: классический и сахарно-питоничий :)

Answer (score 1):

```
number1=[1,2,3]
number2=[1,2,3]
power1=[50,100,150]
power2=[25,150,300]

x1=zip(number1,power1)
x2=zip(number2,power2)
```

Имея на входе два кортежа из списков *[(1, 50), (2, 100), (3, 150)]* и *[(1, 25), (2, 150), (3, 300)]* можно написать просто цикл *for* следующим образом:

```
y=list()
for i, j in zip(x1,x2):
    y.append((i[0],i[1] > j[1]))
```

На выходе получается требуемый вам кортеж *[(1, True), (2, False), (3, False)]*

Comment: Код в цикле можно сократить до: `y.append(i[1] > j[1])`, т.к. значением булевого оператора будет bool. Да и сразу можно положить значение из `i[0]` -> ``y.append((i[0], i[1] > j[1]))``

Comment: Вы правы, так будет короче)